# Review page doesn't indicate already voted posts

Tags: bug, status-completed, review

Posts I've already voted on through normal browsing of the site, are not marked as such (red arrow) in the [review page](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/review/). It's more of an annoyance than a bug, if I try to vote again I get the "already voted, vote is locked" notification and the vote arrow becomes red.

But it's a waste of a second, and those are extremely valuable these days...

Comment: Hmm - it should hide those posts you've already reviewed via the review page. Is this a vote you already made through normal browsing of the site?

Comment: I think that might be too expensive to implement. If you don't get an answer from the devs here (they should be checking the site metas) it would be worth migrating this to MSO to make sure they see it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was an issue with html-encoding some javascript data in the fetched post.

A fix will be deployed tonight or tomorrow.